# What's the difference between default and set default in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, default, alter, postgres-9.6, setdefault

I am kind of new to Postgres and I'm trying to use the following query in Postgres:

`alter table tablename add column col1 enum('r', 'g', 'b') not null set default 'r';`

It is giving me an error. When I changed it to `default` instead of `set default`, it worked fine.

Just wondering what the reason might be!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for "why does it work"?

I suspect that you were using it in one of the following two ways:

```
alter table tablename add column col1 text default 'r';
```

and

```
alter table tablename alter column col1 set default 'r';
```

Note that the former alters the table by adding a column with a default value, while in the latter, the column already exists and you alter the column by setting a default value.

You can find more information about defaults in [create table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) and [alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)